# How to add button at the right corner of Expander - WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, forms, datagrid, window, expander

I would like to know how to put button to the right part of my expander, here is picture of how does it look when my expander is collapsed (I need buttons no matter is it expanded or not).

[image]

I need to get this, so when user click on button I must get ID of order and do some action!
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" Grid.Column="0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"  RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,150,8,50" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="#FF494949"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            </Style>


    <Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightAligElementStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#83D744"/>

    </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}"       Header="Product Name"   Width="0.25*"   Foreground="White" FontSize="20"  FontFamily="Verdana" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"    ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"     Header="Quantity"    Foreground="White"     Width="0.15*"       FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding User}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"     Header="User"        Foreground="White"     Width="0.20*"       FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="#83D744">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DockPanel Height="50">
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Height="25"  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= OrderNumber:# {0}}" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks guys,
Cheers

After Joe's answer I achieved this, but how come there is no button on last item in a DataGrid, take a look at this screenshot:
[image]

CODE:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" Grid.Column="0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"  RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,150,8,50" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="#FF494949"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        </Style>


<Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightAligElementStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#83D744"/>

</DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}"       Header="Product Name"   Width="0.25*"   Foreground="White" FontSize="20"  FontFamily="Verdana" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"    ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"     Header="Quantity"    Foreground="White"     Width="0.15*"       FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding User}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"     Header="User"        Foreground="White"     Width="0.20*"       FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>



    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DockPanel Height="50" Width="{Binding
                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                                          Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                          AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                                                          Path=ActualWidth}">
                                            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Test Button" Margin="0,0,28,0"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" Height="25" Foreground="#83D744" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= Order Number:# {0}}" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

So for strange reason **button on last item is not visible**...

Comment: You're adding a custom TextBlock as the header already, just add the button too, in the <Expander.Header> Dock panel

Comment: Yes, but how to move it right? to the right corner of Expander.Header?

Comment: It's in a dock panel, use DockPanel.Dock="Right"

Comment: Can you post little bit more code how that should be look? I tried but button did not moved to the right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, I've come across this problem before. If you select the DockPanel component you can quickly see the issue, the container that holds the header content is aligned "Left" instead of "Stretch", so the dock panel aligning something on the right doesn't result in what you want:

[image]

As the dock panel itself is stuck in "Left" alignment, even if we set it to "Stretch".

A workaround is to use some bindings so set it's width:

```
   <Expander.Header>
        <DockPanel Height="50" Width="{Binding
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                  Mode=FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                                Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Test" Margin="0,0,28,0"/>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Height="25"  Foreground="Black" Text="Heading" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
```

Resulting in:

[image]

However it's not ideal. Notice I've had to pad out the right of the button with `Padding="0,0,28,0"` otherwise it's pushed off the screen.

A better solution would be to create your own style for the expander.

**Edit.** Given the problems you're facing (which are really weird) I think the best solution is to re-template the expanded so it is correctly structured using a grid. Here's an example:

```
<Expander.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="ContentRow" Height="0"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Background="Green">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Border Padding="6,4" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Path Name="Arrow"
                                            Fill="Black"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Data="M 0 0 L 8 8 L 16 0 Z"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill"
                                                Value="LightGreen" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill"
                                                Value="DarkGreen" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data"
                                                Value="M 0 8 L 8 0 L 16 8 Z" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity"
                                                Value="0.5" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                        Margin="4" 
                                        ContentSource="Header" 
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ContentRow" Property="Height"
                        Value="{Binding ElementName=Content,Path=DesiredHeight}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Expander.Template>
```

It means you have to change the way it looks (but it looks like you want to do that anyway). If you notice, the header ContentPresenter is in a grid, so stretches the full length of the Expander. I also had to do a custom toggle button.

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Everything is clear mate, I didn't understand width part very well but I will try to figure it out

Comment: How come mate that I can't see button on last item in a DataGrid let me post screenshot for you. Check for edit on my post

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird. I can't think of any reason it would do that. Would you post your updated code too?

Comment: Hey mate, I will edit my post and post my new code, where  button on last item is not visible

Comment: I realized that is happening because of this part `Width="{Binding
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                             Mode=FindAncestor,
                                           AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                                         Path=ActualWidth}"` and also it locks vertical and horizontal sliders, its impossible to move them in vertical case up and down. So I need to scroll with my mouse if I want to see bottom of grid

Comment: friend I realize replacing `AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}`   with this,`AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}` I can get button on every item, but then I can't use my vertical slider

Comment: Does the vertical slider appear, just you can't click on it, or does it not appear at all?

Comment: It appears but its not function I can't use it to scroll down and up, also what I realized is next: when I set this to be width of my DockPanel I CAN MOVE BUTTONS RIGHT AND ALSO USE VERTICAL SLIDER BUT SOMEHOW THAT BREAKS MY MAIN WINDOW SO I HAVE TO SCROLL LIKE 20PX TO THE RIGHT TO SEE MY BUTTON`Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ActualWidth}"` and I can use right margin to move my button inside of screen, but still my Main is broken and I can scroll left-right with horizontal slider because screen is broken :(

Comment: I managed to reproduce it using your code. It's really weird, the scroll bar even highlights when you mouse over it, it just doesn't accept input. I'll do some more experimenting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124567/discussion-between-roxypro-and-joe).

Comment: Added a better solution.

Comment: Will check it in a moment

Comment: @Joe is there a way to bind a command from a view model to a button in the expander?

Answer (score 0):

Define a button DataTemplate:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateButton">
        <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Button"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Set the Expander HeaderTemplate:

```
  <Expander  IsExpanded="true" Grid.Column="0" HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateButton}">
```