# Accessing Name value of Grouped Header WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid tied to an `ObservableCollection` that uses `CollectionView` for grouping and sorting.  The grouped headers all have a button in them (found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748539/how-to-add-button-at-the-right-corner-of-expander-wpf-datagrid) post as an answer for that), and in order to find the group name to pass back to the view model I am doing the following in the button click event handler:

```
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainViewModel vm = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        DockPanel dp = (DockPanel) b.Parent;
        FrameworkElement x = (FrameworkElement)dp.Parent;
        GroupItem g = x.TemplatedParent as GroupItem;
        string name = g.Content.ToString();
        CollectionViewGroup cvg = g.Content as CollectionViewGroup;
        name = cvg.Name.ToString();
}
```

This does work, but I feel like there must be an easier way, that could use a bound property in my `ViewModel`, but these headers don't have any customizable binding outside the `Name` and number of items, both of which are automatic.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You could `Bind` group name to `Tag` property of that button, but that's as dirty as handling the click event.

Comment: The `Name` property returns the value of the property that you group by. What else are you looking for here?